# How to fill the treeTableView correctly

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, treetableview

I have a record in database which being get must be in the tree table view. Here is the filling method:

```
 private void updateGoods(){
        goodsPane.setCenter(goodTreeTableView);
        List<Good> goodAndFoldersList;
       try {
           goodAndFoldersList = goodsService.getGoods();//database query
       }catch (SQLException e){
           goodAndFoldersList = new ArrayList<>();
           log.log(Level.ERROR, e.getMessage());
       }
           List<Good> goods = new ArrayList<Good>();//list for roots
           List<Good> roots = new ArrayList<Good>();//list for goods themselves
           for (Good good : goodAndFoldersList) {
               if (good.isIs_folder()) {
                   roots.add(good);
               } else {
                   goods.add(good);
               }
           }
           TreeItem<Good> rootItem = new TreeItem<>();//the main root
           for (Good root : roots) {
               Long folderId = root.getId();
               TreeItem<Good> rootTreeItem = new TreeItem<>(root);
               for (Good good : goods) {//looking for goods for each folder
                   if (good.getFolderId() == folderId) {
                       TreeItem<Good> goodTreeItem = new TreeItem<>(good);
                       rootTreeItem.getChildren().add(goodTreeItem);
                   }
               }
               rootItem.getChildren().add(rootTreeItem);//adding every folder to the main root
           }        
           goodTreeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(rootItem);
    }
```

after this method user doesn't see anything in the treeTableView. Maybe there nessessary to define cell content, but this code being put before `goodTreeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(rootItem);` drops NullPointerException:

```
        goodName.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Good, String> param) ->
                new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getName()));
        folderId.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Good, Number> param) ->
                new ReadOnlyLongWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getFolderId()));
        is_folder.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Good, Boolean> param) ->
                new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().isIs_folder()));
```

I guess this is the reason of my problem but why this drops `NPE` I can't figure out.

**UPD:** if I add setting cell value factory I get the following stacktrace:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/javaEdi/linkserver/ediagent/target/classes/com/ediagent/edi/gui/Main.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2565)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2403)
    at com.ediagent.edi.gui.Main.initRootLayout(Main.java:44)
    at com.ediagent.edi.gui.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1546859350.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1712669532.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/157858792.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1225373914.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/152005629.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2560)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ediagent.edi.gui.MainController.updateGoods(MainController.java:309)
    at com.ediagent.edi.gui.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:328)
    ... 28 more
```

**UPD:**rootItem:
[image: rootItem]

Comment: Can you add the complete StackTrace?

Comment: have you checked if roottreeitem is actually getting any variables?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha added stacktrace

Comment: Do you have `updateGoods()` invoked on a separate Thread?

Comment: try goodTreeTableView.setRoot(rootItem) instead of new Treetableview

Comment: @JeremyC. of cource roottreeitem has value. As for se using setRoot(rootItem) instead of new TreeTableView I get the nullPointerException

Comment: @ItachiUchiha No I don't spread it to threads as there are no need

Comment: that means your rootItem is either null or your goodTreeTableView, have you run through your code with debug? to see the value of your rootItem before you try to use it to set up your treetableview?

Comment: @NikitinMikhail If the `goodTreeTableView` is a part of FXML, you should not re-initialize it. But it is not the reason for NPE. Please add code for `MainController`.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha you are right. goodtreetableview was null as far as it was'n initialized but only declared. I did the following: goodTreeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();
        goodTreeTableView.setRoot(rootItem);

Comment: but still see an empty list in gui. I'll add an image in a minute

Comment: @ItachiUchiha it is a part of FXML. the MainController code is in the beginning of the question. method updateGoods. it is invoked on tabSelectionChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the data to an GUI element on FXML, by re-initializing it. Avoid re-initialization of FXML elements.

You can change the signature of `updateGoods()` to :

```
public TreeItem<Good> updateGoods() {
...
}
```

and use it in the `MainController` to set items

```
goodTreeTableView.setRoot(updateGoods());
```

*Preferably, you can also return only data(List) from `updateGoods()` instead of returning a TreeItem. Create it in the Controller and set it as the root of `goodTreeTableView`.*

Comment: If it is a part of fxml, why is it null. Aren't you annotating it with @FXML?

Comment: oh, yes - that was the nullPointerException reason. But in the GUI I still see only empty strings. May it be because of cell value factory is not set for TreeTableColumns?

Comment: I can't set cell value factory as far as treeTableColumns a null, but they are the part of FXML and annotated with @FXML

Comment: I cannot comment unless I see what you are trying to do. Please ask a separate question with specify data.